# From String^ to array<String^>^ in the constructor C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I have the following base class in Managed c++ (CLI)

```
generic<typename TType>
public ref class OsVariable : OsBase{
        OsVariable(int taskId, array<TType>^ initialValue);
...
}
```

Now to make everyone else happy, i need to facilitate the following class

```
public ref class OsString sealed : OsVariable<String^>
{
OsString(int taskId, String^ initialValue);
...
}
```

I have actually been banging my head to figure out how to make this happen.

```
OsString::OsString(int taskId, String^ initialValue)
    :OsVariable<String^>(taskId, { WHAT GOES HERE})
```

Comment: Why does `OsVariable` take an array and `OsString` not take an array?

Comment: This is a requirement to make it work seamlessly. At least if it is at all possible, there is a lot of code surrounding this. The two classes are in use, but dont share a baseclass today.

Comment: `gcnew array<String^>(1)` would work.  But surely that's not what you want, initializing that array isn't possible.  Your OsVariable class needs more constructor overloads.  Like one that takes a TType initialValue, now it is simple.